# verifying CRE => f(z) differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Say we had $f(z) = e^{-y}(x\cos x - y \sin x) + i e^{-y}(y \cos x + x \sin x)$, and I verified that the Cauchy Riemann Equations hold, then does that mean I can use the theorem $f'(z) = \dfrac{ \partial u}{\partial x} + i \dfrac{ \partial v }{\partial x}$?

Comment: You mean $f'(z) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. If you know that the partial derivatives are continuous, yes, you can use it after having verified the CR equations.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes sorry that's what I mean. Can I ask why I can use it? The theorem states that if we have $f(z)$ differentiable then $f'(z) = ...$ but how do we know $f(z)$ is differentiable?

Comment: Because there is the theorem that states that $f$ is complex differentiable at $z$ if and only if $f$ is real differentiable at $z$ (note: not only the partial derivatives must exist, it must be differentiable, continuity of the partial derivatives implies that) and the partial derivatives of the real and imaginary parts of $f$ satisfy the CR equations. So by verifying the CR equations, and observing the continuity of the partials, you have shown complex differentiability. Hence $f'(z)$ exists and $f'(z) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer We have not yet seen this theorem so I instead tried to prove it was differentiable. I found $f(z) = ze^{iz}$ but computing $\frac{f(z+h) - f(z) }{h}$ I find that to be $\frac{e^{zi}e^{hi}}{h}(z+h-ze^{-hi})$ but cannot find this limit as $h \to 0$

Comment: Write $$f(z+h)-f(z) = (z+h)e^{i(z+h)} - ze^{iz} = he^{i(z+h)} + z\left(e^{i(z+h)}-e^{iz}\right) = he^{i(z+h)} + ze^{iz}\left(e^{ih}-1\right).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer but then I'm stuck trying to figure out $\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{e^{ih} -1}{h}$ which I don't know as i'm not really sure what "i" does in a limit

Comment: Do you know the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h}\,?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, 1. But that would give the answer to be $e^{iz}(1+z)$ but surely it is $f'(z) = e^{iz}(1+iz)$

Comment: Well, you have the $i$ in the exponent, so write $$\frac{e^{ih}-1}{h} = i\cdot \frac{e^{ih}-1}{ih},$$ and maybe rename $ih = k$ in the latter.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you.